# How to add empty text box in grid view and get the input values and save in a text file?

Tags: yii2

In yii2 crud application i added a form and have some values,it displayed as a table.i need to add a empty text box corresponding to each entry and do so me functions in it.

I have added two buttons (i.e) Read and write to do some functions,i cannot add empty text box and this buttons too took me to another page, now i need an empty text box so that the user can write values in it and  if i click the write button the values should get stored in a variable and then i can write it to a text file.

my index in view folder is:

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
              'template' => '{update}{delete}{read}{write}',
              'buttons' => [
                'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'delete'),
                    ]);
                },
                'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', $url, [
                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'update'),
                    ]);
                },
                 'read' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('Read', $url, [
                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'read'),
                    ]);
                },
                'write' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('write', $url, [
                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'write'),
                    ]);
                },
                ],



  I need to add text box and get the value from  user without using db.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can send, the value of the `Text Box` with Ajax. Or by  or ...**

The following example: Create an empty text box (bootstrap) and send by `form`

Also create a **Read button** to load the read action. There are also two ways to **change the URL**. by `urlCreator` or ..

**Note**: To send `Text Box` to the action you want, change the first argument to `beginForm`.

```
<?=Html::beginForm(['action'],'post'); ?>  // form action
<?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => [
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
      'id',
      // 'test',

      ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'buttonOptions' => ['style'=>'float:left; margin: 6px;'],
        // 'contentOptions' => ['class' => td tag..],
        'template' => '{update}{delete}{read}{write}',
        'buttons' => [
        'read' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></span>',
            yii\helpers\Url::to(['read', 'id' => $model->id]), [   // default URL : $url
            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'reed'),
                'style' => 'float:left;margin: 6px;',
            ]);
        },

           'write' => function ($url, $model) {
              return Html::beginTag('div', ['class'=>'input-group has-primary has-feedback', 'style' => 'float:unset; margin-left:55px;'])
              .Html::tag('span', '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></i>', ['class' => 'input-group-addon'])
              .Html::textInput("write[$model->id]",'', ['label' => 'sss' ,'class' => 'form-control input-sm'])
              .Html::tag('div', Html::submitButton('Write',  ['id'=>"smt",'class' =>'btn btn-primary btn-sm']), ['class' => 'input-group-btn'])
              . Html::endTag('div');
            },
          ],

         // 'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {  // You also can change URLs
         //   if ($action === 'read') {
         //        $url ='read?id='.$model->id;
         //        return $url;
         //    }elseif ($action === 'write') {
         //        $url ='write?id='.$model->id;
         //        return $url;
         //    }
         //  }
      ],
    ],
]); ?>

<?= Html::endForm();?>
```

If you used **Pjax**, you must put `'data-pjax' => ''`

also can use `$.ajax` for send input... by click event or change event

**In the controller:**

```
  if ( \Yii::$app->request->post() ) {
        print_r(\Yii::$app->request->post());
        #code...
```